# Android - Sending data between server and client

Tags: android, sockets, service, serversocket, android-networking

I am doing an app that will allow people to share files between them. Right now I am trying just to share text, but soon I will change it to Files. But I am having some trouble creating the Socket connection (the 2 devices are already connected via hotspot: one of them is the hotspot; the other one connects to it).

I was going to do a normal java socket connection, but then I read here that if the phone goes to sleep the sockets will close/timeout. The solution that you guys recomended for that problem was using Intent Services.

I created two IntentServices, a ClientCommService and a ServerCommService. I supose that inside the onHandleIntent() method, I should create the sockets and start listening/waiting for any incoming messages (create the stream objects and start the sockets). My problem is that i also want to send messages and I don't know where I should put the logic to send a message this.out.writeObject().
This is important, because i want to create a bidirectional communication, that can be started by any of the members (server or client).

Question 2: Some approaches that i saw here on stackoverflow, only created an IntentService for the Server. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep alive your service even after your phone goes sleep then you need to create `Service` instead of `IntentService`.

Also you need to keep your service as STICKY service.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

     return START_STICKY;
}
```

Remember that this service is running on main thread so you need to take care of your code wont interrupt UI thread.

You can put your client/server logic in `onStartCommand` method.

Comment: So the IntentService doesn't work ? By the way, where should i put the send logic? I want a bidirectional connection..

Thank you for your help

Comment: IntentService managing its queue, so it will be FIFO system but i guess in your case it could be more then one operation will be there. You can write your client server logic inside the onStartCommand method as client and server logic will call independetly.

Comment: Update : i can't put the logic on the onStartCommand because it will give me the networkonmainthread exception. I managed to put it working, but now i am having other problems, with the fact that since i have 2 threads inside a service (that are fired at different times), i am having problems with socket already in use.

Comment: As I said you have to manage your code in separate thread since onStartCommand calling in main thread of android.

Comment: yeah, thanks. That is what i did. The problem that i have now is that since i am firing the service 2 times (in order to fire the 2 threads - send and receive), the code from the startCommand will be repeated, so the serverSocket will be created again and it will give me that error of the address being already in use. I could put the socket as static, but would it be a good pratice?

Comment: I think you don't need to call service twice in order to call two method. You probably need to use IPC technique to call it from implicite activity

Comment: Yeah, i was researching about it, but then i figured out that i could create an unbound socket in the on create method (which will only be called 1 time, even if i run the service again). Then in the onStartCommand i just gave the port (since i was receiving it through the intent, and in the onCreate method i didn't have the intent